# How to update ng-model before ng-click fires in Ionic/Angular?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there a known issue with Ionic (currently running 1.2.4) where the changing of values in select boxes are reflected after ng-click is fired?

In iOS the select box opens up a list on the lower part og the screen, but it's still possible to click elements outside, and that's where my problem comes into play. The click handler has the old value, since ng-click apparently fires before ng-model is updated with the newly selected value.

```
<select ng-options="obj as obj.name for obj in types" ng-model="filter.type">
</select>

<button ng-click="doSomething()">Button text</button>
```